# Invalid Process Attach in KDMF driver

Tags: c, windows, kernel

I am trying to implement a driver, which will read/write memory in the user-space process. For that, I need to get the process base address. I am using this function for that:

```
PVOID GetProcessModuleAdress(IN PEPROCESS __process,IN PUNICODE_STRING ModuleName)
{
    KAPC_STATE kapc;
    KeStackAttachProcess(__process, &kapc);
    PPEB pPeb = PsGetProcessPeb(__process);
    __int32 pid = PsGetProcessId(__process);
    // Debug
    for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink; pListEntry != &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList; pListEntry = pListEntry->Flink)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Module: (%wZ)\n", pEntry->BaseDllName);
    }
    // End Debug
    for (PLIST_ENTRY pListEntry = pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink; pListEntry != &pPeb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList; pListEntry = pListEntry->Flink)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(pListEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        if (&pEntry->BaseDllName == ModuleName)
        {
            KeUnstackDetachProcess(&kapc);
            return (PVOID)pEntry;
        }
    }

}
```

And I found that this function gives BSOD with Invalid_Process_Attach. I assume that the KeStackAttachProcess function is responsible for this. But since this is default function in windows kernel, I doubt that error is in there. Something wrong is with parameters. KAPC_STATE is doubtfull here, because, it is being defined right in front of the function call. This leaves the PEPROCESS __process parameter. And it comes from:

```
NTSTATUS FindProcessByName(IN CHAR* process_name, IN PEPROCESS* process)
{
    PEPROCESS sys_process = PsInitialSystemProcess;
    PEPROCESS cur_entry = sys_process;

    CHAR image_name[15];

    do
    {
        RtlCopyMemory((PVOID)(&image_name), (PVOID)((uintptr_t)cur_entry + 0x450) /*EPROCESS->ImageFileName*/, sizeof(image_name));

        if (strstr(image_name, process_name))
        {
            __int32 active_threads;
            RtlCopyMemory((PVOID)&active_threads, (PVOID)((uintptr_t)cur_entry + 0x498) /*EPROCESS->ActiveThreads*/, sizeof(active_threads));
            if (active_threads)
            {
                *process = cur_entry;
                return STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }
        }

        PLIST_ENTRY list = (PLIST_ENTRY)((uintptr_t)(cur_entry)+0x2F0) /*EPROCESS->ActiveProcessLinks*/;
        cur_entry = (PEPROCESS)((uintptr_t)list->Flink - 0x2F0);

    } while (cur_entry != sys_process);

    return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

My first assumption was, that it is not modifying the __process parameter, so I implemented a simple check for that:

```
if (FindProcessByName("someprocess.exe", &__process) != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        DbgPrint("Process Not found");
        goto end;
    }

    if (__process == temp)
    {
        DbgPrint("__process is not valid");
        goto end;
    }
```

But it seems to get past it and execute further. This is where I am stuck now. Most frustrating thing is that I am unable to launch full WinDbg in VirtualBox, because it can't run games, and I need to run this driver locally, without any breakpoints.

P.S. My structs are:

```
typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA
{
    ULONG Length;
    UCHAR Initialized;
    PVOID SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA, * PPEB_LDR_DATA;

typedef struct _PEB_LDR_DATA32
{
    ULONG Length;
    UCHAR Initialized;
    ULONG SsHandle;
    LIST_ENTRY32 InLoadOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY32 InMemoryOrderModuleList;
    LIST_ENTRY32 InInitializationOrderModuleList;
} PEB_LDR_DATA32, * PPEB_LDR_DATA32;

typedef struct _PEB
{
    UCHAR InheritedAddressSpace;
    UCHAR ReadImageFileExecOptions;
    UCHAR BeingDebugged;
    UCHAR BitField;
    PVOID Mutant;
    PVOID ImageBaseAddress;
    PPEB_LDR_DATA Ldr;
    PVOID ProcessParameters;
    PVOID SubSystemData;
    PVOID ProcessHeap;
    PVOID FastPebLock;
    PVOID AtlThunkSListPtr;
    PVOID IFEOKey;
    PVOID CrossProcessFlags;
    PVOID KernelCallbackTable;
    ULONG SystemReserved;
    ULONG AtlThunkSListPtr32;
    PVOID ApiSetMap;
} PEB, * PPEB;

typedef struct _PEB32
{
    UCHAR InheritedAddressSpace;
    UCHAR ReadImageFileExecOptions;
    UCHAR BeingDebugged;
    UCHAR BitField;
    ULONG Mutant;
    ULONG ImageBaseAddress;
    ULONG Ldr;
    ULONG ProcessParameters;
    ULONG SubSystemData;
    ULONG ProcessHeap;
    ULONG FastPebLock;
    ULONG AtlThunkSListPtr;
    ULONG IFEOKey;
    ULONG CrossProcessFlags;
    ULONG UserSharedInfoPtr;
    ULONG SystemReserved;
    ULONG AtlThunkSListPtr32;
    ULONG ApiSetMap;
} PEB32, * PPEB32;

typedef struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY
{
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderLinks;
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;
    LIST_ENTRY InInitializationOrderLinks;
    PVOID DllBase;
    PVOID EntryPoint;
    ULONG SizeOfImage;
    UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;
    UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;
    ULONG Flags;
    USHORT LoadCount;
    USHORT TlsIndex;
    LIST_ENTRY HashLinks;
    ULONG TimeDateStamp;
} LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, * PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY;

typedef struct _LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY32
{
    LIST_ENTRY32 InLoadOrderLinks;
    LIST_ENTRY32 InMemoryOrderLinks;
    LIST_ENTRY32 InInitializationOrderLinks;
    ULONG DllBase;
    ULONG EntryPoint;
    ULONG SizeOfImage;
    UNICODE_STRING32 FullDllName;
    UNICODE_STRING32 BaseDllName;
    ULONG Flags;
    USHORT LoadCount;
    USHORT TlsIndex;
    LIST_ENTRY32 HashLinks;
    ULONG TimeDateStamp;
} LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY32, * PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY32;
```

P.S. Yea, this code is a bit pasted, I know. I am trying to learn kernel programming in practical way :)
Would like to hear in detail, why this is failing.

Comment: are you a File system filter driver?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: what is the type of driver? is it a file system filter driver? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers

Comment: This driver is using process memory and is not accessing file system. I found that, this BSOD may be caused by that, I am trying to attach to the process second time without calling KeUnstackDetachProcess. This is weird, because I have call for KeStackAttachProcess only one time.